Site is not indexed by Google. All technical SEO implementation is as per executed (see ticket)
Introduction
The blog is hosted at my subdomain.
The main domain is dormant and un-used.
On-Page SEO
Sitemap and robots.txt is only configured for the subdomain:

Robots.txt is here: https://blog.shafikwalakaka.com/robots.txt

Robots.txt does not block any pages
Robots.txt points to the sitemap


Sitemap has all the relevant pages that are planned to be listed here: https://blog.shafikwalakaka.com/sitemap.xml

The main domain does not have any sitemap and robots.txt configured.
The subdomain also has the following implemented:

Follows robots tag
Index robots tag

Google Search Console
Sitemaps has already been submitted, on 31 Mar 2024. 23 Sites were discovered which was expected:
Image showing Google Search Console processed sitemaps successfully
However, only 2 sites were indexed by google even though Google Search console found 23 sites in the sitemap:
Image showing Google Search Console only finding 2 sites
See screenshot when listing searching for the following in google site:blog.shafikwalakaka.com:
Google Search showing only 2 sites that are listed
This is also supported by the indexed list in the google search console:
Image showing the indexed list in Google Search Console itself
Workaround
If we request the indexing manually via Google Search Console, then the page is listed:
Image showing how we request indexing manually from Google
See screenshot for the page that has now been listed by Google:
Image of a page that is indexed after requesting manually
Example (For additional context)
The example aims to show that the page has met all technical SEO requirements but is not indexed until we manually request for Google to index it:

Access Google Search Console, and inspect the following URL: https://blog.shafikwalakaka.com/canine-chronicles/how-to-potty-train-your-dog
Google Search Console indicates that the page is not indexed:
Image showing that Google Search console indicating that the page is not indexed
Hit the Test Live URL button to check details of the page hosted on that URL.
Google indicates that we can index the page, and we manually initiate the request to index
Image showing Google indicating that the page can be indexed, and we can manually request to index
We will monitor after reqeusting, the page should be made available in google search in a few hours. It can be verified by accessing: site:blog.shafikwalakaka.com in google search

Thank you
Please let me know if there is any other information that could help.
Thank you.

It sounds like its a new site.  Google can take months to index a new site.  It is just not trusted.  We all have to go through that.
The best thing to do is

Submit it to Bing and perhaps Yandex too.
They are more verbose in what's wrong with your site. Fix everything
Use a site such as Ahrefs to check your pages.  Fix everything
Use a site to check your html and css.  Fix everything.
Keep adding new pages and keep changing the content.
See if you can get some other site to give you a backlink (but don't purchase it).

Once you have a site that has no faults and complies with Google (and other's) rules, you have to wait patiently.

Noted with thanks. So there is nothing I can do for You're right it's a brand new site.
So we can manually fix this by manually inspecting each URL in Google Search Console, and manually requesting for it to be indexed?
You can see based on the following search query site:blog.shafikwalakaka.com, that the How to Potty Train Your Dog site is now listed.
This was manually requested (as per defined in the last para in the issue description)
